# Linked list function - C

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function that creates a linked list out of an array:

```
typedef struct {
    char airplane_name[AIRPLANE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
    char airplane_model[MODEL_LENGTH];
    float age;
    struct plane *next_plane;
} plane;

int CreateAirplaneList(plane **plane_input_output) {
plane plane_name_arr[NUM_OF_PLANES] = { {"Beit-Shean", "737", 5}, {"Ashkelon", "737", 10.25}, {"Hedera", "737", 3}, 
{"Kineret", "737", 7.5},{"Naharia", "737", 1}, {"Tel-Aviv", "747", 20}, {"Haifa", "747", 15}, {"Jerusalem","747",17},
{"Ashdod", "787", 1}, {"Bat Yam","787", 1.5}, {"Rehovot", "787", 0.5} };

plane *new_plane = NULL, *list=NULL;

int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PLANES;i++) {
    new_plane = (plane*)malloc(sizeof(plane));
    if (new_plane == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        return FAILURE;
    };
    new_plane = &plane_name_arr[i];
    printf("name%d:%s\n", i, new_plane->airplane_name);
    new_plane->next_plane = list;
    list = new_plane;
    printf("new name%d:%s\n", i, list->airplane_name);
}
printf("all good");
*plane_input_output = list;
return SUCCESS;
};
```

While running it on `main()` with `NULL` as parameter it gets stuck.

```
int main(){
plane **x = NULL;
CreateAirplaneList(x);
return 0;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] and read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "running it on main()". Should you include the definition of `main`?

Comment: Answering aside for a moment, what *exactly* is this code supposed to do? Are you supposed to be making a *copy* of the nodes in your array, placing the copied nodes into a linked list, and returning the head of that list in the output parameter (and apparently the function result too though you didn't bother; why both I have no idea) ? Or are you supposed to be stringing a linked list using the *same* nodes in the array (so no copy, in which case this can't possibly work as-is, as the array is automatic to the function and any pointers to it returned would be dangling) ?

Comment: iv'e edited the code. i'm trying to make a linked list out of the details that are in the array. it doesn't matter to me how, the output( same pointer as the input) should be a pointer to the list

Comment: Well, for starters, that should be `plane *x = NULL; CreateAirplaneList(&x);`

Comment: if i type plane (**x = NULL), doesn't (*x) holds the address of my list head?

Answer (score 3):

Just reading the code and guessing about what it is supposed to do I can see these things:

```
new_plane = &plane_name_arr[i];
```

The above code writes the address of the element in the array to new_plane and
throws away the pointer that you just allocated. You probably want to copy the values from plane_name_arr[i] to the new memory.

```
*new_plane = plane_name_arr[i];
```

You mention you call the method with NULL from main. This won't work either as you write to that memory at the end of the method.

```
*plane_input_output = list;
```

This requires there to be some memory it can write to.

Calling it like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  plane *head = NULL;
  CreateAirplaneList(&head);
}
```

Makes sure that the write at the end of *CreateAirplaneList* can actually write the result somewhere.

Your method `int CreateAirplaneList(plane **plane_input_output)`
takes a pointer to a pointer as an argument. 
If you call it like you do with:

```
plane **x = NULL;
CreateAirplaneList(x);
```

You will pass in the value NULL. Which means the write at the end tries to write to NULL. Since you want to pass the linked list outside of the method you want to provide the method with an address where it can write the result.

So you create a variable of the type you want. In this case `plane *head;` and then you pass the address of that variable to the method `CreateAirplaneList(&head)` so that when the `*plane_input_output = list` it writes it to the memory of `head` in `main`.

There might be more errors in there I haven't seen while quickly looking at it. Good luck.

Comment: i understand the first part of the comment and yes, this is what i wanted to do, tnx.   can you please explain the second part?

Comment: @a_beilis C is a pass-by-value (the conversion of expressed array id's to pointers notwithstanding). To have in/out arguments to a function, you therefore need to do it with a "value" that makes it possible for the called function modify the *caller's* data; that is done by declaring the formal parameter to be a pointer-to-type and passing the address of the thing you want modified at the call site. That the thing you want to modify is a pointer-type itself doesn't change that. It means the formal argument is a pointer-to-pointer to type, and the caller passes the address of a pointer var.

Comment: i understand. this is the reason i choose to pass (plane **). but i seem to be confused. if i declare (plane **x), doesn't (*x) holds the address to x?

Comment: No, if you declare plane *x. &x is the address to x. 
If you do plane y; plane *x = &y; x points to y. x holds the address of y.

Answer (score 2):

With:

```
new_plane = (plane*)malloc(sizeof(plane));
```

you are allocating room for a plane. Then with:

```
new_plane = &plane_name_arr[i];
```

you throw away the memory and replace with a pointer into the planes array. Probably you intend:

```
*new_plane = plane_name_arr[i];
```

which copies the plane data from the array to the allocated memory.

(In your version, the array was a local array, i.e. on the stack, which does not exist anymore after the function returns. Its memory will be reused and your linked list shows garbage.)

In your `main` you must call the function with the address of your list head:

```
  plane *x = NULL;         //  x is the list
  CreateAirplaneList(&x);  // &x is the address of the list
```

The create function can now modify the list in `x`.

Comment: i understand the first part of your comment and yes, this is what i wanted, tnx.   about the second part, i didnt quite understand what you mean

Comment: if i type plane (**x = NULL), doesn't (*x) holds the address of my list head?

Comment: You pass the address of your list so the function can modify the list and your `main` function can now see the modified list. I updated my asnwer; hope it is clear now.

Comment: its clear. but i seem to be confused. can you please answer my last comment?    
"if i type plane (**x = NULL), doesn't (*x) holds the address of my list head? "

Comment: `x` should not be of type `int **x` but of type `int *x`. You pass an `int **` to your function because you take the _adress_ of `int *x`. So in main you only write `int *x=NULL;`.

Comment: @WhozCraig i looked at your example but i cant seem to understand "for (size_t i = 0; i < N_PLANES; ++i)
    {
        *ppList = malloc(sizeof **ppList);
        **ppList = plane_arr[i];
        ppList = &(*ppList)->next_plane;
    }
    *ppList = NULL;